# Automated Creation of Sequential Date/Number Range from Singular Numerical Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to create an sheet where I enter a singular numerical value (0-##) and a singular date in Column A, and Columns C and D will populate a sequential number and date that extend as far as the numerical value is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Cell C1` enter the following formula

```
=IF(ROW()<=$A$2,ROW(),"")
```

Then in `Cell D1` enter

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(C1),$A$4+(ROW()-1),"")
```

or

```
=IF(C1<>"",$A$4+(ROW()-1),"")
```

Drag/Copy down formula as required. Next time on when you'll change values in `Cell A2` and `Cell A4`, `Column C` and `Column D` will populate values accordingly. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  The formula for Column D worked 100%.  However, I noticed that when I inserted headers for Column C and moved the formulas down, the number coincided with the row it was in.  Adding -1 to the second ROW, as you did with the date, resulted in the very last number not being shown.  Any help would be appreciated.

(1) [With headers and without the -1](http://i.imgur.com/xTAeoY3.png)
--
(2) [With headers and with the -1](http://i.imgur.com/wXJhcM2.png)

Comment: @Lanzer - First formula will be `=IF(ROW()-1<=$A$2,ROW()-1,"")`

Comment: @Lanzer - Second formula will be `=IF(ISNUMBER(C2),$A$4+(ROW()-2),"")`

Comment: @Lanzer - Add these formula in `Cell C2` and `Cell D2` respectively

Comment: Done!  Thank you for being patient with me.